# Can I install the Xubuntu 10.04 theme on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, themes, xubuntu

I love the [Xubuntu 10.04 theme](http://gvxdev.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/xub-lucid-scrshot-3.png) and I want to install it on my Ubuntu 11.04. It's possible to install only the theme?

Comment: Do you mean on Xubuntu 11.04 or Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: I'm also a fan of the Xubuntu (11.04) theme. Very nicely done.

Comment: I'm talking about Xubuntu 10.04(ten) theme in Ubuntu 11.04(eleven). I've got my answer, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you want all the xubuntu themes and branding, install the `xubuntu-artwork` package.  Note that this will install the Xubuntu 11.04 themes, if installed on Ubuntu 11.04, etc. (as the repositories all have the same version, regardless of which desktop environment you use).

Be aware that the Xubuntu themes are tested primarily in the XFCE environment: there may be gaps in the coverage when used in a GNOME environment, although it may also be that it works perfectly.

If you are especially attached to the Xubuntu *10.04* theme, and the theme in 11.04 is unsuitable for you, you could potentially forward-port the xubuntu-artwork (and dependency packages) in some private repository (e.g. a PPA).  Note that there may be changes in the theming engines or similar that may affect the work of forward-porting these packages.

Answer (score 1):

The specific theme you are looking for is called Albatross it was designed for Xubuntu 9.10 Karmic if you would like a copy of the gtk theme you can download it at the xubuntu-artwork launchpad site [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/xubuntu-artwork/0.38/+files/xubuntu-artwork_0.38.tar.gz) The tar.gz file contains alot of things as well as the them which is located in

`/xubuntu-artwork-0.38/usr/share/themes/Albatross/gtk-2.0/`

hope this helps

As Emmet has already explained it was designed to be used with Xubuntu so there is no guarantee it will work with ubuntu but you can try if it doesn't work you can switch back to another theme